# Influxdb: How to run task with influx command?

Tags: task, influxdb

I am not able to run task using influx command. I am able to run it via web interface, but I can't do it using CLI. I don't know what [required Run ID](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/cli/influx/task/run/retry/) is:

```
root@b8492e33ab4b:/# influx task list
ID                  Name                                            Organization ID     Organization    Status  Every   Cron
097f6888e870e000    Machine Component Throughput Report - Weekly    b30d680d99926543    xxxxxxxx        active  1d  
root@b8492e33ab4b:/# influx task run retry --task-id=097f6888e870e000 --run-id=097f6888e870e000
Error: 404 Not Found: failed to retry run: run not found
```

I tried different values for run-id but I wasn't successful, e.g.: `failed to decode request: invalid ID` for --run-id=0000000000000000

Any idea how to run the task or how to generate run ID correctly?

Comment: You are mixing two concepts here: a task list and the list of executions of said task. With `influx task run list --task-id 097f6888e870e000` you should get the executions of the task, and `influx task run list --task-id 097f6888e870e000 --run-id whichYouJustFoundOutInTheList` should rerun said execution.

Comment: `influx task run list --task-id 097f6888e870e000` did not run the task immediately. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Again: You cannot. You are mixing two concepts here.

Comment: The influxdb web app allows you to instantly run a task, so I expected the CLI to be able to do that as well. Okay then, thanks for the reply.